# Probability of picking a specific ball if you can choose twice

Tags: probability

I came onto a question which confused me on the way to solve it. Suppose you have a bag which contains 6 distinct balls. One of them is colored black and it is the one you want to obtain. You are only allowed to pick twice.

First scenario is without replacement. My solution to this case is that the first choice will have a probability of 1/6 chance of being the black ball while the second will have a 1/5 chance. Since the two cases are dependent (as choosing the first ball without replacement will change the probability for the second pick) then I should add the probabilities which gives me a total of 11/30=0.366 chance of choosing a black ball from the two picks. The confusion for me is that following this logic, if I were to have 3 picks then I would need to do 1/6 + 1/5 + 1/4 =0.61 chance of getting the black ball. And if I were to continue with this pattern I should expect the probability to reach one if I were allowed to pick 6 times without replacement. However, if I calculate 1/6 + 1/5 + 1/4 + 1/3 + 1/2=1.45. If I'm allowed to pick 5 times, the probability exceeds one which as far as I know should not be possible. So I'm inclined to believe that my approach is wrong and would like to understand where exactly is the problem and what is the proper way of solving this question.

The second scenario is with replacement. Every time you pick a ball you put it back in the bag. Since every draw is now independent, and you can only draw twice, I assume the probability of drawing a black ball would be 1/6 * 1/6 =1/36. Once again, the result doesn't make any since if I continue with this logic. Following this approach, the more times I'm allowed to pick, the probability of picking a black ball seems to get smaller and smaller which is counterintuitive to me. With more picks, I expect the probability to increase not decrease.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: For the replacement case:  it's easier to work backwards.  The probability that a given draw is non-black is $\frac 56$ so the probability that two in a row are non-black is $\frac {25}{36}$.   Without replacement...well, you are seeing two out of six, so...

Comment: @lulu I see what you are saying, but I would like a bit more explanation for why my way of looking at the case without replacement leads into a contradiction. It seems I'm overcomplicating the problem but I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

As requested in the comments:

Let's do the "without replacement" case the way you started.

There are two paths to success:  $BN$, $NB$ where $B$ denotes the black ball and $N$ denotes any of the non-black balls.  The probability of the first is $\frac 16\times 1$ and the probability of the second is $\frac 56\times \frac 15=\frac 16$  so the answer is $\frac 26$.

Your initial claim "the first choice will have a probability of 1/6 chance of being the black ball while the second will have a 1/5 chance"  is wrong.  The Black one is equally likely to appear in any draw.  A correct version of the statement would be:  the probability that the second is $B$ given that the first one was $N$ is $\frac 15$.  Thus, a conditional probability.

Think of it this way:  suppose you were going to draw all out all six balls in sequence.  Drawing randomly means that all orders are equally probable, so any particular ball is equally likely to appear in any place of the sequence.  Thus the probability that $B$ is first is $\frac 16$, as is the probability that it is second, third, fourth, etc.

For completeness:  in the "with replacement case" the events are independent and, of course, the case $BB$ is now possible.  In such a situation, it is often best to work backwards, as there is just a single case, $NN$ in which you fail to draw $B$.  The probability that a single selection is $N$ is $\frac 56$ so the probability of $NN$ is $\frac 56\times \frac 56=\frac {25}{36}$.  It follows that the probability of drawing at least one $B$ this way is $$1-\frac {25}{36}=\frac {11}{36}$$.  Note that this is slightly less than $\frac 13$, the probability in the "no replacement" scenario.  This is intuitive, I think, since if you don't replace then each failure improves the chances on the next try.  After all, if you took $6$ balls then you are sure to win without replacement but with replacement you fail with probability $\left ( \frac 56\right)^6\sim .3349$, so failure is not rare.

Comment: It’s clear now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In your without replacement case, your formulation is incorrect because you are not taking into account the fact  that for the second ball to be black, the first ball **must** have been white, thus applying the [general multiplication rule of probability](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch05-rul.html) the correct probability is

$\dfrac56\cdot\dfrac 15= \dfrac16$

Similarly, for the black ball to be found at position $3$,

Pr$=\dfrac56\cdot\dfrac45\cdot\dfrac14 =\dfrac16$

In fact, as has been pointed out in a comment, the probability of the black ball being found at **any** position will be seen to be $\dfrac16$ for the simple reason that  the black ball has no reason to prefer one position over another .

Answer (score 0):

Without replacement: There will be two of six balls in your hand and four of six in the bag. The probability that the black ball is one of the two in your hand is 2/6. If you draw k balls the probability that the black ball is one of the k in your hand is k/6.